# Applying for Thai tourist visa from tier 3 Indian city

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, thailand, vfs-global

Currently I'm situated in a district near Nagpur, Maharashtra. I will be travelling to Thailand on 28th Aug. Although, it may be true that Indians can avail visa on arrival, I don't want to be at the mercy of the immigration officers as I have read some deportation stories on the topic. So, I decided to apply through vfs global. However, it seems like I need to go in person to their office in Pune/Mumbai. I'm a working class person, so it'd be difficult for me to take leave before my original journey begins. Is there any way to get Thai visa online completely or by travelling to Nagpur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to get Thai visa online completely or by travelling to Nagpur?

There aren't any Thai representation in Nagpur and as an Indian citizen residing in India, you aren't eligible for the Thai [e-visa](https://www.thaievisa.go.th/).

However, you are eligible to apply to the pre-approved *e-visa on arrival scheme* that is to be applied online at [VFS e-VOA](https://thailandevoa.vfsevisa.com/thailand/online/home/index) fully online, but keep in mind, this is only a part of the visa (a good part as you don't have to worry about payment and you have a fast-track line at the VOA desk and most issues will have been ironed out already if your approval is issued), the officer at the desk will still make an assessment as with every other applicant and then issue the actual VOA.

From the VFS site above :

> > As soon as you arrive in Thailand with the pre-approved E-VOA, follow the steps mentioned below:
>
> - Go to the Visa on Arrival area in the immigration area and enter the dedicated E-VOA lane
> - Present your passport to the officer
> - Get the final immigration approval and enter Thailand

> I don't want to be at the mercy of the immigration officers as I have read some deportation stories on the topic

Entering a country of which you don't hold citizenship is *never* a right, but a privilege and this is considering whatever previous permission you got (outside of exceptions that likely don't apply to you), you can have your visa revoked and being denied entry over whatever, they can do *"whatever they want"* with you when you're seeking entry to a foreign country.

Comment: Much appreciated. Let me check out the links applicable in my case.